# Clone project: refused to execute script

Tags: installation

I just cloned an empty Drupal 8 project locally, initially I entered the web folder and I used

```
php -S localhost: 8000
```

With this virtualization, every time I enter the "edit" rooting rule, a 404 error occurs.
To solve the problem I created a vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *: 80>
ServerName www.site.lcl
DocumentRoot /home/user/Projects/platform/site/app/web
 <Directory "/home/user/Projects/platform/site/app/web">
   Allowoverride all
   Order allow, deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
 </ Directory>
</ VirtualHost>
```

With this configuration the routes are presented correctly, but a new error occurs, in all the pages the css and js files are not loaded and from console js this error appears:

Refused to execute script from 'http: //www.site.lcl/' because its MIME type ('text / html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

I tried to edit the php.ini file like this: default_mimetype = "", restart apache and clear the cache but with no result.

In both installations the php.ini file used is the same.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Did you uncomment `RewriteBase /` in your `.htaccess`?

Comment: yes, I tried that too

Comment: In the bash line it says port 8000, your virtual host says port 80, does this matter?

Comment: And did you run Drupal cron and flushed Drupal caches at least once?

Comment: Did you try to change permissions and ownership recursively for your /sites/default/files directory?

Comment: @leymannx let's go every time

Comment: Do the CSS/JS files that the browser returns a 404 for actually exist on disk?